# Facing issue while forming cluster in NiFi 1.0.0

Tags: hortonworks-data-platform, apache-nifi

Configured the cluster nodes as per the reference of below given link

https://pierrevillard.com/2016/08/13/apache-nifi-1-0-0-cluster-setup/

Heart beat is sent and received by the cluster master node But NiFi UI is not launching in the browser, while seeing the nifi-app log file I can see below exception what will be the root cause of the issue ?

> com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientHandlerException:
>   java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect    at
>   com.sun.jersey.client.urlconnection.URLConnectionClientHandler.handle(URLConnectionClientHandler.java:155)
>   ~[jersey-client-1.19.jar:1.19]    at
>   com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client.handle(Client.java:652)
>   ~[jersey-client-1.19.jar:1.19]    at
>   com.sun.jersey.api.client.filter.GZIPContentEncodingFilter.handle(GZIPContentEncodingFilter.java:123)
>   ~[jersey-client-1.19.jar:1.19]    at
>   com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource.handle(WebResource.java:682)
>   ~[jersey-client-1.19.jar:1.19]    at
>   com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource.access$200(WebResource.java:74)
>   ~[jersey-client-1.19.jar:1.19]    at
>   com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource$Builder.get(WebResource.java:509)
>   ~[jersey-client-1.19.jar:1.19]

[image]

Comment: Can you check the nifi-app.log on all three instances and see if there are any different errors?

Comment: No, same error occurs in all three instances when I try to launch the UI in the browser @Bryan Bende

Answer (score 1):

Please upgrade to JDK 11
and Apache NiFi 1.12.1 (or wait a few weeks for 1.13)

https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/administration-guide.html

Answer (score 0):

The link you refer to is of an old beta version (so the exact cause may not be proven) however, based on [this situation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49157530/nifi-connection-refused-in-gui-after-installation) on a sligtly less old version:

1. Check that all nodes can talk to eachother
2. Check that all nodes can talk to themselves
3. Ensure there is no internal/external/localhost name inconsistency

If any of this needs to be fixed, check /etc/hosts or your DNS