# Nifi - "Connection refused" in gui after installation

Tags: apache-nifi

I'm installing a three node non-secure nifi cluster (1.5) with embedded zookeeper.

The installation has completed, the cluster startup up and election have finished, without any obvious issues.

However when I hit the gui I see the following:

javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)

In nifi-apps.log there is:

```
2018-03-07 14:41:37,857 WARN [Replicate Request Thread-7] o.a.n.c.c.h.r.ThreadPoolRequestReplicator Failed to replicate request GET /nifi-api/flow/current-user to test-nifi01:8080 due to javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
2018-03-07 14:41:37,858 WARN [Replicate Request Thread-7] o.a.n.c.c.h.r.ThreadPoolRequestReplicator 
javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.internal.HttpUrlConnector.apply(HttpUrlConnector.java:284)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientRuntime.invoke(ClientRuntime.java:278)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation.lambda$invoke$0(JerseyInvocation.java:753)
    ....
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
    ....
```

in nifi-user.log:

```
2018-03-07 15:18:49,475 INFO [NiFi Web Server-21] org.apache.nifi.web.filter.RequestLogger Attempting request for (<no user found>) POST http://test-nifi01:8080/nifi-api/access/kerberos (source ip: 172.100.1.11)
2018-03-07 15:18:49,476 INFO [NiFi Web Server-21] o.a.n.w.a.c.IllegalStateExceptionMapper java.lang.IllegalStateException: Access tokens are only issued over HTTPS.. Returning Conflict response.
2018-03-07 15:18:49,572 INFO [NiFi Web Server-17] org.apache.nifi.web.filter.RequestLogger Attempting request for (<no user found>) POST http://test-nifi01:8080/nifi-api/access/oidc/exchange (source ip: 172.100.1.11)
2018-03-07 15:18:49,573 INFO [NiFi Web Server-17] o.a.n.w.a.c.IllegalStateExceptionMapper java.lang.IllegalStateException: User authentication/authorization is only supported when running over HTTPS.. Returning Conflict response.
2018-03-07 15:18:49,672 INFO [NiFi Web Server-23] org.apache.nifi.web.filter.RequestLogger Attempting request for (anonymous) GET http://test-nifi01:8080/nifi-api/flow/current-user (source ip: 172.100.1.11)
```

It's the same results regardless of what host I connect to.

I'm not sure what I need to be checking here.

EDIT: Updated with more detail.

Node1:
https://pastebin.com/5nMzWfXw

```
# web properties #
nifi.web.war.directory=./lib
nifi.web.http.host=test-nifi01
nifi.web.http.port=8080
nifi.web.http.network.interface.default=eth0
nifi.web.https.host=
nifi.web.https.port=
nifi.web.https.network.interface.default=
nifi.web.jetty.working.directory=./work/jetty
nifi.web.jetty.threads=200
nifi.web.max.header.size=16 KB
nifi.web.proxy.context.path=


# cluster node properties (only configure for cluster nodes) #
nifi.cluster.is.node=true
nifi.cluster.node.address=test-nifi01
nifi.cluster.node.protocol.port=11003
nifi.cluster.node.protocol.threads=10
nifi.cluster.node.protocol.max.threads=50
nifi.cluster.node.event.history.size=25
nifi.cluster.node.connection.timeout=5 sec
nifi.cluster.node.read.timeout=5 sec
nifi.cluster.node.max.concurrent.requests=100
nifi.cluster.firewall.file=
nifi.cluster.flow.election.max.wait.time=5 mins
nifi.cluster.flow.election.max.candidates=
```

Node 2: https://pastebin.com/n5GMy1nA

```
# web properties #
nifi.web.war.directory=./lib
nifi.web.http.host=test-nifi02
nifi.web.http.port=8080
nifi.web.http.network.interface.default=eth0
nifi.web.https.host=
nifi.web.https.port=
nifi.web.https.network.interface.default=
nifi.web.jetty.working.directory=./work/jetty
nifi.web.jetty.threads=200
nifi.web.max.header.size=16 KB
nifi.web.proxy.context.path=

# cluster node properties (only configure for cluster nodes) #
nifi.cluster.is.node=true
nifi.cluster.node.address=test-nifi02
nifi.cluster.node.protocol.port=11003
nifi.cluster.node.protocol.threads=10
nifi.cluster.node.protocol.max.threads=50
nifi.cluster.node.event.history.size=25
nifi.cluster.node.connection.timeout=5 sec
nifi.cluster.node.read.timeout=5 sec
nifi.cluster.node.max.concurrent.requests=100
nifi.cluster.firewall.file=
nifi.cluster.flow.election.max.wait.time=5 mins
nifi.cluster.flow.election.max.candidates=
```

Node 3: https://pastebin.com/EqztLfnD

```
# web properties #
nifi.web.war.directory=./lib
nifi.web.http.host=test-nifi03
nifi.web.http.port=8080
nifi.web.http.network.interface.default=eth0
nifi.web.https.host=
nifi.web.https.port=
nifi.web.https.network.interface.default=
nifi.web.jetty.working.directory=./work/jetty
nifi.web.jetty.threads=200
nifi.web.max.header.size=16 KB
nifi.web.proxy.context.path=


# cluster node properties (only configure for cluster nodes) #
nifi.cluster.is.node=true
nifi.cluster.node.address=test-nifi03
nifi.cluster.node.protocol.port=11003
nifi.cluster.node.protocol.threads=10
nifi.cluster.node.protocol.max.threads=50
nifi.cluster.node.event.history.size=25
nifi.cluster.node.connection.timeout=5 sec
nifi.cluster.node.read.timeout=5 sec
nifi.cluster.node.max.concurrent.requests=100
nifi.cluster.firewall.file=
nifi.cluster.flow.election.max.wait.time=5 mins
nifi.cluster.flow.election.max.candidates=
```

Anyone have any thoughts on what I should be looking at?

EDIT 2:

It's looks like each node is refusing to connect to itself. E.g on node 2 we have

```
2018-03-07 20:31:08,099 WARN [Replicate Request Thread-4] o.a.n.c.c.h.r.ThreadPoolRequestReplicator Failed to replicate request GET /nifi-api/flow/current-user to test-nifi02:8080 due to javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
```

and a curl also fails:
    [taas@test-nifi02 logs]$ curl http://test-nifi02:8080
curl: (7) Failed connect to test-nifi02:8080; Connection refused

Curls to the other nodes are fine. The same behavior is occurring on each node, e,g node1 can't curl to node1 and node3 can't curl to node3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have dns enabled for network/subnet . if you dont have luxury of dns try updating  /etc/hosts  files with the exact ip address and hostnames

ex:

192.168.0.1 test-nifi01
192.168.0.2 test-nifi02

in all the hosts of the nifi nodes then try connecting it. and also make sure to check if you can able to connect from one node to another node by using shell via ssh

Comment: I'll accept this since it sent me in the right direction. The actually issue is that nifi can't seem to accept  connections from both localhost and another interface (at least not that I can find). In my case the hosts file is set up so requests to the host name resolves to localhost - which nifi won't accept connections from if eth0 is set to the default interface.

Answer (score 1):

In a NiFi cluster, a request comes in to one node, and then that node replicates the request to all other nodes.

This issue shown nifi-app.log is indicating that the connection was refused between the current node test-nifi01:8080.

I assume you have hosts like test-nifi01, test-nifi02, and test-nifi03, so each of these nodes would need to be able to resolve the other hostnames. You can start by issuing a ping from one node to the other two, and do that on each node.

Comment: Confirmed each host can resolve and ping all the others. Firewalld has been disabled to rule that out. Which port is the replication happening on?

Comment: Its happening on the web port, you can see in the error message "Failed to replicate request GET /nifi-api/flow/current-user to test-nifi01:8080"

Comment: Can you show the config for all three nodes like did for node 1 one above?

Comment: Added the web and node config above and linked to the complete nifi.properties for reference

Comment: Updated once more to add - it looks like each node is refusing connections to itself, which might be the problem. Don't know why it's doing this though,

Comment: Something in your /etc/hosts or DNS might not correct, looking at your curl command... notice how you curled against "test-nifi02" but the error says "ue-uat-nifi02" so when a NiFi nodes is sending a request to it self it would fail if the url is being resolved to the second one because that's not the host you have NiFi listening on.